# Parallel automation of web scraping with Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a database, which collects requests from users. Each request consists of two main info: timestamp (date and time field) and task the system needs to do in backend (logged) page. On defined time in request the Python script opens certain webpage, log in with provided user's login data, and do the task defined in the request. In praxis it happens that the system needs to log in to the same URL for different users (ie. 100 requests at the same time). That is quite resource consuming (RAM and vCPU) as that all runs on virtual server.

I would like to achieve that each request (execution of Python) is run in its own kubernet. Before execution of Python there should be mechanism established to initiate the kubernet for each request (sometimes there are as little as 7 or 10, but there may be several hundred requests too).

**My question:** how to achieve that with Kubernetes? Is there any better solution than Kubernetes? Any suggestion will be much appreciated.